# Getting the last Date record in SQL in WHERE condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have these rows in a table:

```
CarRentId   LicensePalte    UserId     StartDate     ReturnDate
1           29-456-15       1          2015-07-10    2015-07-15
50          29-456-15       2          2015-08-11    2015-08-15
```

When I query for date in where condition I want the result to be the last row and not the first one.

that is the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  ManufacturerName,
  ModelName,
  CreationYear,
  Gear,
  CurrentKM,
  Picture,
  DATEDIFF(D, '2015-08-12', '2015-08-15') * PricePerDay AS [Totalprice],
  PricePerDay,
  PricePerDayDelayed,
  InventoryCars.LicensePlate,
  CarsForRent.RentalReturnDate
FROM Models
JOIN Manufacturers
  ON Models.ManufacturerID = Manufacturers.ManufacturerID
JOIN InventoryCars
  ON InventoryCars.ModelID = Models.ModelID
JOIN CarsForRent
  ON CarsForRent.LicensePlate = InventoryCars.LicensePlate
WHERE RentalReturnDate < '2015-08-12'
ORDER BY ManufacturerName, ModelName
```

Instead of getting 2015-08-15, the result I get is 2015-07-15 for the that specific LicensePlate number.

Comment: What query? what result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select distinct 
 ManufacturerName, ModelName, CreationYear,Gear, CurrentKM, Picture,
DATEDIFF(D, '2015-08-12', '2015-08-15')*PricePerDay as [Totalprice],PricePerDay,
PricePerDayDelayed, InventoryCars.LicensePlate,

(select max(RentalReturnDate) from CarsForRent where LicensePlate=InventoryCars.LicensePlate) as [RentalReturnDate]

from Models
join Manufacturers 
 on Models.ManufacturerID=Manufacturers.ManufacturerID
join InventoryCars
 on InventoryCars.ModelID=Models.ModelID
join CarsForRent
 on CarsForRent.LicensePlate=InventoryCars.LicensePlate
where RentalReturnDate<'2015-08-12'
order by ManufacturerName, ModelName
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a lot of speculation, but regarding what I read from your question, I'm thinking that you might want the latest return date from your stack. If so, then you can do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  ManufacturerName,
  ModelName,
  CreationYear,
  Gear,
  CurrentKM,
  Picture,
  DATEDIFF(D, '2015-08-12', '2015-08-15') * PricePerDay AS [Totalprice],
  PricePerDay,
  PricePerDayDelayed,
  InventoryCars.LicensePlate,
  CarsForRent.RentalReturnDate
FROM Models
JOIN Manufacturers
  ON Models.ManufacturerID = Manufacturers.ManufacturerID
JOIN InventoryCars
  ON InventoryCars.ModelID = Models.ModelID
JOIN CarsForRent
  ON CarsForRent.LicensePlate = InventoryCars.LicensePlate
WHERE RentalReturnDate < '2015-08-12'
ORDER BY CarsForRent.RentalReturnDate, ManufacturerName, ModelName
```

This code basically will check the latest return date, if they have the same return date, it will order by manufacturer name, and if by chance both are the same, it will order by model name.